# how to make jquery line move to correct list item?

Tags: jquery

My problem is that the line changes its size but doesn't move to the correct list item, as I would like it too.

Could someone lead me in the right direction in fixing this problem?

I created a fiddle, to test my magic line.
http://jsfiddle.net/753JF/

and here is the Jquery

```
$(function() {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#bar");
    $("#magic-line").remove();
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#bar li a").hover(function () {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function () {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic line only needs to appear on hover over the item or li and not all the time. The width etc. that has been fixed is static... i.e. outside the hover.